# EBADCSRFTOKEN: Invalid CSRF token in expo auth session

Tags: expo, azure-ad-b2c

I am using expo auth session and Azure ADB2C to authorize my mobile React Native app. I am using the Expo auth session proxy. When I try to log in to the app, I get an error that reads "EBADCSRFTOKEN: Invalid CSRF token" in the browser on my first attempt to log in. Subsequent attempts work fine. Other threads have recommended possible solutions, but none of them are applicable as far as I know, since we are using Azure's ADB2C.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is creating new session every time which is causing issue

CSRF tokens have two parts. The token embedded in the form, and a corresponding token somewhere else, be it in a cookie, stored in a session or elsewhere. This use of elsewhere stops a page being self contained.

If you include the string to hash in the request, then the request is self contained, so copying the form is all an attacker needs to do, as they have both parts of the token, and thus there is no protection.

Even putting it in the form URL means that it's self contained, the attacker simply copies the form and the submission URL.

One half could be kept in session, or it could be dropped via a cookie. It doesn't have to be stored on the server at all, usually it's cookie based so you don't have to rely on enabling sessions.

Few recommended solution for Invalid CSRF token : https://blogs.sap.com/2014/07/11/issues-with-csrf-token-and-how-to-solve-them/